# Background Fetch working every Second in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, background, fetch, alarm

Behold. I am trying to create an IOS app with swift 4.2, which, according to my client, has to sound an alarm, but it can only be stopped with a QR code. Therefore, what I will need will be a timer that works in the background, checking the time every second, because something else, the user could stop it, without the QR code. The only thing I've found for that is the Background Fetch, but can it work with 1 second checks every time?

Does anyone have a better idea?

Cheers

This is my source code for now

App delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(2.0)
}

//ini----------------------------background task
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // fetch data from internet now
    let time:TimerNow = TimerNow();
    let hours = preferences.string(forKey: "hours");
    let minutes = preferences.string(forKey: "minutes");
    if((hours == time.getHours())&&(minutes == time.getMinutes())){
        lem.onPlayCommand();
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
//fin ---------------------------background task
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use local notifications instead. It will be fired when you want to notify about the elapsed time. You could cancel it whenever and with any condition you want.

IMO timer and background fetching is not suitable for that situation.

Comment: Thank you. I had already thought about it, but I need something that allows me to run a script recursively. Since the sound will be looped until the QR reading, could this do it? Do you have an example?

Comment: I need some script that run a function when hour and minutes match. And Music must to play automatically with the notificiation